# PHP query execute without error but return count 0

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, pdo

I am creating login in angularjs, in login.phppage   i am verify whether user exist or not by number of rows exist or not means using rowCount() in php pdo but it always return 0 result. here is my php file:

```
<?php
   /*
   * Collect all Details from Angular HTTP Request.
   */ 
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $email = $request->email;
    $pass = $request->password;



    $user ="root";
$pass ="m2n1shlko";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog_db', $user, $pass);

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `signup_tbl` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `password`='$pass'");
$query->execute();
$count = $query->rowcount();
if($count>0){

echo "You have sucessfully login with this Email: ".$count; //this will go back under "data" of angular call.

}else{


  echo "Error While Authentication with this Email: " .$count;
}


    /*
     * You can use $email and $pass for further work. Such as Database calls.
    */    
?>
```

---

Data from the controller get here I didn't know where i am missing the code. Apreciate if help .. Thanks

Comment: what is this $count = $query->filepro_rowcount(oid)(); in your code??

Comment: check your query once.

Comment: it run , i test it on mysql console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its  `$query->rowCount()`; NOT `$query->rowcount();`

```
 $count = $query->rowCount();
 if($count>0){
 echo "You have sucessfully login with this Email: ".$count; //this will go back under "data" of angular call.
 }else{
 echo "Error While Authentication with this Email: " .$count;
 }
```

Read Manual [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite `$pass` to database (line 13) and for user (line 8). Change database password to `$db_pass`.

```
...
$email = '...';
$pass = $request->password;
...
$db_pass = '...';
...
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog_db', $user, $db_pass); // $pass to $db_pass
```

Comment: Now after changing variable i m getting error on console

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @RahulSaxena: are you sure you changed it twice? In database declartion (line 13) and in line 15?

Comment: Its resolve sir.. Thanks its a silly mistake as you told me  variable overwrite

Answer (score 0):

I have done in my local system,it's working good,Try like below example,this is working fine.just follow this example and do your code right way:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "xxx";
// Create connection
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', $username, $password);

$query =$conn->prepare("select * from testing");
$query->execute();
$count = $query->rowCount();
echo "Counting:".$count;
?>
```

**Output:-**

```
Counting:3
```